# Elasticsearch: multi_match phrase_prefix query with multiple search terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a database with entries like

```
title: This is my awesome title
abstract: A more detailed descriptions of what [...]
```

I would like to build an Elasticsearch query that matches the above document with, e.g.,

```
awe detai
```

In words: A multi_match phrase_prefix query with multiple search terms. (This is intended to be used as a search-as-you-type feature.)

I see how you can combine multi_match and phrase_prefix, but it's unclear to me how to do this for multiple search terms.

Any hints?

Comment: Did you try using `terms` inside `filter`? As per [the doc](http://elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html)

Comment: awe detai so you mean if user typed that you want to find an document?

Answer (score 5):

Well there is few ways to do that

```
POST stack/autocomplete/1
{
  "title": "This is my awesome title",
  "abstract": "A more detailed descriptions of what"
}
```

Then you can search using query string with star but problem here is that you need to append asterix to query

```
POST stack/autocomplete/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "title",
        "abstract"
      ],
      "query": "awe* detai*"
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to match on user query then you can use like that

```
POST stack/autocomplete/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "fields": [
        "title",
        "abstract"
      ],
      "query": "awesome tit",
      "type": "phrase_prefix"
    }
  }
}
```

One more option to consider would be to use [nGram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) with query string so you will not need to modify user query "awe* detai*"